# C++ Passing a function to a function using functors

Tags: c++, function, functor

I have two functors:

```
class SFunctor {
public:
    SFunctor(double a) { _a = a; }
    double operator() (double t) { return _a * sin(t); }
private:
    double _a;
};

class CFunctor {
public:
    CFunctor(double b) { _b = b; }
    double operator() (double t) { return _b * cos(t); }
private:
    double _b;
};
```

I want to pass one or the other of these functions to another function:

```
double squarer(double x, ??______?? func) {
      double y = func(x);
      return y * y;
}
```

In my main program I want to make a call like this:

```
CFunctor sine(2.);
SFunctor cosine(4.);
double x= 0.5;
double s = squarer(x, sine);
double c = squarer(x, cosine);
```

How do I specify the function fund, that is what goes in front of it in place of ??**_**?? ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do it with templates

```
template <class F>
double squarer(double x, F& func) {
      double y = func(x);
      return y * y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not knocking on the above template answer. In fact, it may be the better choice of the two, but I wanted to point out that this can be done with polymorphism as well. For example...

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class BaseFunctor {
 public:
   virtual double operator() (double t) = 0;
 protected:
   BaseFunc() {}
};

class SFunctor : public BaseFunctor {
 public:
   SFunctor(double a) { _a = a; }
   double operator() (double t) { return _a * sin(t); }
 private:
   double _a;
};

class CFunctor : public BaseFunctor {
 public:
   CFunctor(double b) { _b = b; }
   double operator() (double t) { return _b * cos(t); }
 private:
   double _b;
};

double squarer(double x, BaseFunctor& func) {
   double y = func(x);
   return y * y;
}

int main() {
   SFunctor sine(.2);
   CFunctor cosine(.4);
   double x = .5;
   cout << squarer(x,sine) << endl;
   cout << squarer(x,cosine) << endl;
}
```

I ensured that this was a full working demo, so you can just copy it to test it. You will indeed observe two different numbers print to the terminal, thus proving that polymorphism can be used with functors. Again, I'm not saying this is better than the template answer, I just wanted to point out that it isn't the only answer. Even though the question has been answered, I hope this helps inform anyone who wants to be informed.